# Absurd Results in SciPy Curve Fitting

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, astronomy

I have a really huge array named `diff` and I have used `np.histogram` to generate its histogram `hist`.
I want to fit `diff` to a gaussian for which I wrote this function:

```
def gauss(x,disp,amp,mu,sigma):
    return disp+amp*norm(mu,sigma).pdf(x)

popt,pcov=curve_fit(gauss,diff,hist,p0=(0,40,0,0.1))
popt
```

and I have done the curve fitting as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

x=np.linspace(-12.5,12.5,1000)
p=gauss(x,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3])

plt.hist(diff,bins=len(diff))
plt.plot(x, p)
```

The plot I get is this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBV2L.png)
which is obviously absurd. I have tried to play with parameters `p0` in the curve fitting function but that really isn't helping. Have I made any other blunder here?(Let me know if `diff` and `hist` are required, I'll add a link to that)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have set the histogram as one of the arguments to the curve_fit function, which doesn't make sense. Assuming `len(x) == len(diff)` what you want is something like

```
x=np.linspace(-12.5,12.5,1000)
diff = # a data point for every value in x
popt,pcov=curve_fit(gauss,x, diff, p0=(0,40,0,0.1))
```

Alternatively, if you DO want to fit to the histogram, something like

```
x_hist = np.linspace(-12.5, 12.5, len(hist)) # X axis of the histogram
popt,pcov=curve_fit(gauss, x_hist, hist, p0=(0,40,0,0.1))
```

Comment: I want to fit the histogram of `diff` to a Gaussian. I think you misunderstood.

Comment: @Qwertie Ok, that's not really clear from your question. Something like the second snippet in the answer I just added then? Point is, in either case you need an X axis corresponding to the data you want to fit.